# The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an Error log table, We insert error details into this table if there is any exception in stored procedure or trigger.

I can see an entry for an update trigger in this table. But I am not able to understand the root cause of the error.

Is this trigger causing the issue? or some other stored procedure is causing this issue?

**Error Message:** The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.

**Procedure Name:** In the procedure name I get the trigger name

**Error Number:** 3930
Query to insert into an error log table.

```
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    INSERT INTO Mas_ErrorLog (ProcedureName, ErrorNumber, ErrorMessage, ErrorSeverity, ErrorState, ErrorLine)  
    SELECT Error_Procedure(), Error_Number(), Error_Message(), Error_Severity(), Error_State(), Error_Line()  
END CATCH
```

**Note**: Just to highlight one thing, I can't see an entry for this trigger in other environments databases like Dev, Beta or UAT. It's occurring only in the Production database so I cannot directly make changes and test.

And it's an old log, I cannot reproduce this case, I need to investigate the root cause.

Comment: Most likely the transaction was doomed due to `XACT_ABORT ON` being on by default in triggers. Don't try to write to the database in the trigger CATCH block if `XACT_STATE() = -1`.

Comment: @DanGuzman and why it went into catch? How can I know this?

Comment: The standard `CATCH` block I use in triggers is simply `THROW;` and let the application log errors as desired. Logging SQL errors using T-SQL isn't very robust since there are cases where the error cannot be logged.